# Interpreting Tensorflow/Tensorboard "subtraction" operation

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

The following is code adapted from a simple learning example, that I have bent out of shape to understand the Tensorboard graph visualizations:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Create 100 phony x, y data points in NumPy, y = x * 0.1 + 0.3
x_data = np.random.rand(10).astype("float32")
y_data = x_data * 0.1 + 0.3

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0, name = "internal_W"), name = "external_W")
b = tf.Variable(2*tf.zeros([1], name = "internal_b"), name = "doubled_b")
y = (W * x_data + b)


l1 = (y - y_data)
l2 = (y_data - y )
writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/test1", sess.graph_def)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph.
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(y))
print('---')
print((y_data))
print('---')
print(sess.run(l1))
print('---')
print(sess.run(l2))
```

A sample output of the print statements is:

```
[ 0.84253538  0.31011301  0.11627766  0.35491142  0.65550905  0.1798114
  0.13632762  0.02010157  0.42960873  0.04218956]
---
[ 0.39195824  0.33384719  0.31269109  0.33873668  0.37154531  0.31962547
  0.31487945  0.302194    0.3468895   0.30460477]
---
[ 0.45057714 -0.02373418 -0.19641343  0.01617473  0.28396374 -0.13981406
 -0.17855182 -0.28209242  0.08271924 -0.2624152 ]
---
[-0.45057714  0.02373418  0.19641343 -0.01617473 -0.28396374  0.13981406
  0.17855182  0.28209242 -0.08271924  0.2624152 ]
```

Clearly, the subtractions are working properly-- the inputs to the subtraction are in different order, and yield different outputs.  However, the graph visualization is:

[image: Tensorboard Screenshot]

Notice the "Sub" operators, which appear not to reverse the order of the operands as the code does.  (Highlighting either operator yields no additional insight.)  Am I missing something obvious, or do the node visualizations completely obscure order of operands?

Answer (score 1):

After futzing around with this, my considered answer to my own question is, "Yes, this is working as intended."  The inputs to the nodes show only what the inputs are, not any particular relationships to the operation or the node or themselves; indeed, if one added a variable to itself in an operation node, the input variable would show up only once.

This is not a design choice I would have made, but that does seem to be the intent.

I still encourage others who may have more insight to comment or fully answer.